# How continually output text to a RichTextBox with it being visually noticeable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop, while-loop, richtextbox

I am just trying to make my own VB project right now to get familiar with the language, and all I would like for it to do is continually print a string to the next line in a RichTextBox.
The issue that I can't figure out is to have it print one after another, it is printing all at once. Ill have some code down below to show where I am at right now.

I've tried using different counting methods, and depending on how it is set up, the debugger won't even load...

```
Friend WithEvents TableLayoutPanel1 As System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
End Sub
Private Sub RTB1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim counter1 As Integer = 0
    Dim i As String = "- I" & vbCrLf

    While counter1 <= 10
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()
        i = i + i
        counter1 += 1
    End While

    RichTextBox1.Text = i


    'Loop

    'Environment.NewLine

End Sub
Friend WithEvents TableLayoutPanel2 As System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel

Private Sub TableLayoutPanel2_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel2.Paint

End Sub
Friend WithEvents RichTextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
```

Thank you to anyone that takes the time to look at this and help me out!
I really am looking for my output to scroll down the RichTextBox and continually to output a string on a new line over and over again one at a time.

Comment: Move `Timer1.Interval = 1000 Timer1.Start()` to the `Shown()` event of the Form. Add the rest of the code in the `Tick()` event of your Timer. Use the `RichTextBox.AppendText()` method to add text. Also important, set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` `ON` in the project properties.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting this to work... I gave it a try and it doesn't even print

Comment: Here you go. See if you can set it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described:

- Create a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer). There are different types of Timers available. This is the one you need to update an UI component, since it's Tick event is raised in the UI thread.
- Initialize the Timer and set its Interval to 1 second (`1000 ms`). The initialization is performed in the [Shown()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) event of the Form, which is raised when the Form is ready to be presented (see the Docs).
- Add the [Timer.Tick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick) event handler (here is added in code)
- Initialize an Integer field (here, called **`timerCounter`**) which is incremented each time the Timer Ticks.
- In the `Tick` event, add a line of text to the RichTextBox control using it's [AppendText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext) method, which allows to add text to the control without clearing it. This method is common to all controls that inherit `TextBoxBase`.

Note:
I'm adding the text to the RichTextBox using an interpolated string `$"{Some value}"`. If your version of VB.Net doesn't suppport it, use the older format:

```
RichTextBox1.AppendText("Line number " & timerCounter.ToString() & Environment.NewLine)
```

---

```
Private rtbTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
Private timerCounter As Integer = 0

Protected Sub TimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    timerCounter += 1
    RichTextBox1.AppendText($"Line number {timerCounter} {Environment.NewLine}")
    RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    rtbTimer = New Windows.Forms.Timer With { .Interval = 1000 }
    AddHandler rtbTimer.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
    rtbTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it!! Thank you very much for taking the time to do that!

Comment: Well, I'm glad it was helpful :)